# Unexpected behavior with linq Except() method

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> aList = new List<string>();
        List<string> bList = new List<string>();
        List<string> answerList = new List<string>();
        aList.Add("and");
        aList.Add("and");
        aList.Add("AND");
        aList.Add("And");
        aList.Add("not");
        aList.Add("noT");
        bList.Add("NOt");
        answerList = aList.Except(bList, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();

        foreach (var word in answerList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }
```

The expected behavior of the above program is to remove all the occurrences of "not" in aList and return {and, and, AND, And}. It seems "StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase" has removed all the duplicates of the word "and" and returned just one occurrence of {and} in answerList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation of `Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Produces the **set difference** of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

So, `Except()` returns a *set*, which means it returns each string at most once. And since you're telling it that case should be ignored, you're getting the output you're getting.

To work around that, use a method that doesn't operate on sets, like `Where()`:

```
answerList = aList.Where(
    a => !blist.Contains(a, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```

This approach is slow (O(*a* · *b*)) when compared with `Except()` (O(*a* + *b*)), but that shouldn't be a problem for short sequences.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Accepting your answer since you have given the work around.

Answer (score 3):

This is the result I intuitively would expect.

Except returns the set difference, and you explicitly state that you want case insensitive comparison to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you trying to tell that what results actually we get is unexpected? Do you have any idea why this is so?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that Except is a set operation - it treats the input as a set. In a set each value is either included or excluded - there can be no duplicates.